# Rang-slider or similar solution to avoid overlapping of label in Y axis in Plotly

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, charts, plotly

I can not find the solution to my question. I made a plot with Plotly express, does range slider exist for Y axis? I already implemented range slider for X axis as follow, but the Y axis is messy, I was trying to come up with an solution but I can not implement rang slider on y axis, is there any way to make this chart performing better?

```
def chart(df)

    color_discrete_map = {'df1': 'rgb(255,0,0)',
                      'df2': 'rgb(0,255,0)',
                      'df3': '#11FCE4',
                      'df4': '#9999FF',
                      'df5': '#606060',
                      'df6': '#CC6600'}


    fig = px.scatter(df, x='DATE', y='CODE', color='SOURCE', width=1200,
                     height=800,color_discrete_map=color_discrete_map)

    fig.update_layout(xaxis_type='category')
    fig.update_layout(yaxis={'dtick':1})

    fig.update_layout(
        margin=dict(l=250, r=0, t=0, b=20),

    )
#     fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(tickformat="%y-%m", tickmode = 'linear',  tick0 = 0.5,dtick = 0.75))
        # Add range slider
    fig.update_layout(
        xaxis=dict(
            rangeselector=dict(
                buttons=list([
                    dict(count=1,
                         label="1m",
                         step="month",
                         stepmode="backward"),
                    dict(count=6,
                         label="6m",
                         step="month",
                         stepmode="backward"),
                    dict(count=1,
                         label="YTD",
                         step="year",
                         stepmode="todate"),
                    dict(count=1,
                         label="1y",
                         step="year",
                         stepmode="backward"),
                    dict(step="all")
                ])
            ),
            rangeslider=dict(
                visible=True
            ),
            type="date"
        )
    )
   

           # Add range slider
    fig.update_layout(yaxis={'dtick':1})

    fig.update_xaxes(tickformat = '%Y-%B', dtick='M1')


    fig.update_xaxes(ticks= "outside",
                     ticklabelmode= "period", 
                     tickcolor= "black", 
                     ticklen=10, 
                     minor=dict(
                         ticklen=4,  
                         dtick=7*24*60*60*1000,  
                         tick0="2016-07-03", 
                         griddash='dot', 
                         gridcolor='white')
                    )
    


    st.plotly_chart(fig)

    return
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Plotly does not support slider option for y-axis. but there are someways like zooming:

```
fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(fixedrange=False)
```

using above code you will let user to zoom in on a specific region and have a clear view.

or you can explore annotation to highlit a specific data or filter out your data.

Comment: Thanks but this doesnt provide clear view on Y axis, just x axes

Comment: as told there is no way to do it for Y-axis Plotly doesn't allow that you need to enable or instruct user to zoom in the image to have clear view or you can use filtering where you can filter down the Y-axis list to smaller list.